# How to keep Foundation Off-Canvas open while using web page

Tags: javascript, css, html, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation's Off-Canvas navigation, however I want to be able to keep it open while I scroll and click around on a web page. Clearly it wraps everything with a big div, which when clicked, closes the the off-canvas area. I want to be able to keep it open, but I don't see an easy way of manipulating it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching and asking some user groups, it does not seem possible. I ended up just building a custom equivalent to do as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but found out you can use the reveal class for this, like so:

```
<div class="off-canvas position-right reveal-for-medium" id="offcanvas-1" data-off-canvas>
```

You can use all the breakpoints classes for this as wel so instead of reveal-for-medium, you can also use reveal-for-large for example.

See also the docs: https://get.foundation/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#reveal-on-larger-screens

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in case anyone should come across it, Foundation 6 has a plugin option for this:

Name: data-close-on-click
Type: boolean
Default: true
Description: Allow the user to click outside of the menu to close it.

From: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#js-options

So to enable it, initialize your offCanvas like this:

```
...
var options = {
  data-close-on-click: false
};
var elem = new Foundation.OffCanvas(element, options);
...
```